# Eigen: How to update the values of a SparseMatrix?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Is there some way to do the following?

```
for(int i = 0; i < M.cols(); i++){
    for(InnerIterator it(M,i); it; ++it){
        it.value() = 1;
    }
}
```

Right now, if I start with a sparse matrix `M`, I make `M'` with the triplet init:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M.cols(); i++){
    for(InnerIterator it(M,i); it; ++it{
        triplet_vec.emplace_back(it.row(),it.col(),3.);
    }
}
// and init the new sparsemat
Mnew.setFromTriplets(triplet_vec.begin(),triplet_vec.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a to change all the non-zero values in an existing matrix to a constant (as I understood from your question), then you can always iterate over the non-zeros as such:

```
for (int k=0; k<mat.outerSize(); ++k)
    for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k); it; ++it)
        it.valueRef() = my_constant_value;
```

This does not incur a binary search for each set of indices. See [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) (header **Iterating over the nonzero coefficients**) for more details.